# How do i add aria-label to an iFrame?

Tags: typescript, quicksight-embedding

I am trying to embed quicksight iFrame to angular application, here is the code is there a way to add aria label?

```
const frameOptions = {
url: embeddedURL,
container: this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#experience-container'),
scrolling: "no",
height: this.iFrameHeight,
width: "100%",
locale: "en-US",
footerPaddingEnabled: true,
overflow: "hidden",
onChange: (changeEvent, metadata) => {
    switch (changeEvent.eventName) {
        case 'FRAME_MOUNTED': {
            console.log("Frame Mounted");
            break;
        }
        case 'FRAME_LOADED': {
            console.log("Frame Loaded");
            break;
        }
    }
},
};
const contentOptions = {
locale: 'en-US'
};
await embeddingContext.embedDashboard(frameOptions, contentOptions);
};
```

Tried adding as label in div but didnt work